# iTerm2 History Timestamp to Human Readable

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, time

I can see all commands entered into iTerm doing the following:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2/ShellHistory.sqlite

sqlite>  select * from ZCOMMANDHISTORYCOMMANDUSE;
```

The output looks like this:

```
54171|1|1||22159|5120|642127758.695336|cat wolf_password|/Users/franks|6978AA30-BD92-4949-9C28-6B77F525DE51
```

The 7th column looks like a timestamp in milliseconds but it's not epoch, which would be:
`GMT: Tuesday, May 8, 1990 12:49:18.695 AM`, which is incorrect, this command was run within the last couple of years.

Table schema shows:

```
sqlite> .schema ZCOMMANDHISTORYCOMMANDUSE
CREATE TABLE ZCOMMANDHISTORYCOMMANDUSE ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZCODE INTEGER, ZENTRY INTEGER, Z_FOK_ENTRY INTEGER, ZTIME FLOAT, ZCOMMAND VARCHAR, ZDIRECTORY VARCHAR, ZMARKGUID VARCHAR );
CREATE INDEX ZCOMMANDHISTORYCOMMANDUSE_ZENTRY_INDEX ON ZCOMMANDHISTORYCOMMANDUSE (ZENTRY);
```

It's `ZTIME FLOAT`

Given the above, what human-readable date and time is `642127758.695336`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command executed on May 8 2021 at 00:49:18 UTC.

If we take a look at the [iTerm2 source code](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/c52136b7c0bae545436be8d1441449f19e21faa1/sources/iTermShellHistoryController.m#L676) for history storage, we notice that that `now` is defined as the following:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)now {
    return [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}
```

If we then take a look at the [`NSDate` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1417376-timeintervalsincereferencedate) for `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, we notice that Apple uses a different epoch than UNIX. Any time based on this property will calculate seconds from January 1 2000 at 00:00 UTC.